# How to handle multiple commands for the same state type

Tags: corda

I have a use case where in one atomic transaction I would like to transition two or more states of same type to different lifecycle. ( i.e. )

```
val x : SomeState
val y : SomeState
```

- `x` should transition to Approved with `Command.Approve`
- `y` should transition to Audited with `Command.Audit`

How can the contract code run the `verifyApprove` only on `x` while running `verifyAudit` on `y`. 
There can be an infinite numbers of `SomeState` that can transition to different *lifecycles* in the same atomic transaction.

Do I have to make `Command.Approve` have a constructor with a `List<UniqueIdentitifer>` so it can determine on which states to run its corresponding verify function. 
Subsequently populate the command in the flow?

Answer (score 1):

Every `verify` function verifies a transaction in its entirety, and not its individual states. However, you can easily write logic within `verify` to control how each state type is checked. For example, if the `XState` and `YState` states share the same contract, you could do:

```
class XAndYContract: Contract {
    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val inputXStates = tx.inputsOfType<XState>()
        val outputXStates = tx.outputsOfType<XState>()
        val inputYStates = tx.inputsOfType<YState>()
        val outputYStates = tx.outputsOfType<YState>()

        requireThat {
            "All XState inputs are unapproved." using (inputXStates.all { it.approved == false })
            "All XState outputs are approved" using (outputXStates.all { it.approved == true })
            "All YState inputs are unaudited." using (inputYStates.all { it.audited == false })
            "All YState outputs are audited" using (outputYStates.all { it.audited == true })
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example. You have the full capabilities of Java/Kotlin at your disposal to control which states are checked and how.

Another option would be to split the logic into two contracts - `XContract` and `YContract`. Then you would have:

```
class XContract : Contract {
    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val inputXStates = tx.inputsOfType<XState>()
        val outputXStates = tx.outputsOfType<XState>()

        requireThat {
            "All XState inputs are unapproved." using (inputXStates.all { it.approved == false })
            "All XState outputs are approved" using (outputXStates.all { it.approved == true })
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
class YContract : Contract {
    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val inputYStates = tx.inputsOfType<YState>()
        val outputYStates = tx.outputsOfType<YState>()

        requireThat {
            "All YState inputs are unaudited." using (inputYStates.all { it.audited == false })
            "All YState outputs are audited" using (outputYStates.all { it.audited == true })
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** The examples above assume there are two types of states. Suppose there is only one state type:

```
class MyState(val lifecycle: Lifecycle, override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier) : LinearState {
    override val participants = listOf<AbstractParty>()
}
```

Where `Lifecycle` is defined as:

```
enum class Lifecycle {
    ISSUED, AUDITED, APPROVED
}
```

And we want to impose the rule that in each transaction, any inputs in the `ISSUED` stage are transitioned to `APPROVED`, and any inputs in the `APPROVED` stage are transitioned to `AUDITED`.

We could achieve this using `groupStates`:

```
class MyContract : Contract {
    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val groups = tx.groupStates { it: MyState -> it.linearId }

        requireThat {
            for (group in groups) {
                val inputState = group.inputs.single()
                val outputState = group.outputs.single()
                when (inputState.lifecycle) {
                    Lifecycle.ISSUED -> {
                        "Issued states have been transitioned to approved" using (outputState.lifecycle == Lifecycle.APPROVED)
                    }
                    Lifecycle.APPROVED -> {
                        "Approved states have been transitioned to audited" using (outputState.lifecycle == Lifecycle.AUDITED)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`groupStates` works by grouping inputs and outputs together based on some rule. In our case, we are grouping inputs and outputs that share the same `uniqueIdentifier`. We can then check that each input has evolved into the corresponding output correctly.

Comment: The example you gave illustrates when x and y are two distinct type of state/contract. I would like to have both x and y as the same type of state and contract. 
i.e `listOf(x,y) : List<SomeState>`

Both `x` and `y` is of the same state that started off with a field `lifecycle` populated as `ISSUED`. It is during one atomic transition, `x` needs to transition 
to `APPROVED` because the flow determines it meets certain criteria, while `y` needs to transition to `AUDITED` because of its own criteria. How would you ensure the commands run the correct verify on x and y of the same state type?

Comment: Edited the response to give an example of this use-case as well.

Comment: but our case is `ISSUED` can go either be `APPROVED` or `AUDITED`. Both inputs in the `tx` is in `ISSUED`, one of them goes to `APPROVED`, another goes to `AUDITED`. And if there’s two commands, how do they differentiate between each state transition?

Comment: Well it really depends on your use-case. You need to think about what constraints make the transaction invalid, and write the `verify` accordingly. Is the constraint that there must be two inputs, and one goes to `Approved` while the other goes to `Audited`? Then impose a constraint on the number of `Approved` vs `Audited` outputs. You know the constraints you want to impose, so you'll have to customise the logic accordingly.

Comment: I have similar need and I am trying to figure out as well.The whole commands thing is too complicated I am not sure why it is designed such a way. Why would not you be able to specify within Commands it self what states it should take care. Not sure why Commands needs to be disconnected from States at the time time of building transaction.

Comment: That's an interesting point. I've heard others grumble about the inability to map commands to specific states. Can you raise this on the corda-dev mailing list to get the thoughts of Mike and others?

Answer (score 0):

To implement that functionality you just have to use use a switch statement on the command. For example, in verify(tx) you could do something like this:

```
when (command.value) {
        is Commands.Approve -> verifyApprove(tx, setOfSigners)
        is Commands.Audit -> verifyAudit(tx, setOfSigners)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unrecognised command")
}
```

while the commands could be defined as follows:

```
interface Commands : CommandData {
    class Issue : TypeOnlyCommandData(), Commands
    class Transfer : TypeOnlyCommandData(), Commands
}
```

and in verifyApprove() and verifyAudit(), you can do your verification.

Comment: When using `when()` clause the first command in the `if-else` contract will be used on `all` the states that are involved in the transaction.

Comment: You can also break the transaction into multiple transactions in the same flow and then segregate the verification using the commands. And if you don't want to break the transaction then I think you have to use two different states

Answer (score 0):

I tried passing states into the command itself so that we know command needs to take care what states. In verify method then don't check for single command.

```
interface Commands : CommandData {
    class Create(val outputStates:List<MyState>): TypeOnlyCommandData(), Commands
    class Update(val inOutStates:List<InOutState<MyState>>): TypeOnlyCommandData(), Commands
   }
 ................
@CordaSerializable
data class InOutState<T: ContractState>(val inputState: T, val outputState:T)
 ............
 tx.commands.forEach {

            when (it.value) {
                is Commands.Create -> {
                   val cmd = it.value as Commands.Create

                    requireThat{

                        "Output states must be present" using (cmd.outputStates.isNotEmpty())
                    }
             }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

One more pattern is to set the Corda contract Command into the State Object and do the grouping by the Command during time of contract verification

```
@CordaSerializable
interface CommandAwareState<T:CommandData>: LinearState,QueryableState{

     val command: T
}

============
interface LinearStateCommands<T : LinearState> : CommandData {


    fun verify(inOutStates: List<InOutState<T>>, tx: LedgerTransaction)
}
===========


data class StateA(val attribX: String, val attribY: String
                 , override val command: StateAContract.Commands = 
                  StateAContract.Commands.None()): 
                       CommandAwareState<StateAContract.Commands>
 ============

 open class StateAContract : Contract {
companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    val CONTRACT_ID = "com.myproj.contract.StateAContract"
}

interface Commands : LinearStateCommands<DocumentState> {

    class None(): TypeOnlyCommandData(), Commands{
        override fun verify(inOutState: List<InOutState<StateA>>, tx: 
                         LedgerTransaction) {

                requireThat {
                    "There should not be any Input and Outputs" using 
                     (inOutState.isEmpty())
                }

        }


    }

     class Create(): TypeOnlyCommandData(), Commands{

          override fun verify(inOutStates: List<InOutState<DocumentState>>, tx: 
       LedgerTransaction) {
        //WRITE Contract verification
        }  
     }

override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {

           tx.matchLinearStatesByCommand(DocumentState::class.java).forEach{

               it.key.verify(it.value,tx)
           }
    }
 }
==========

inline fun <T,reified  K : CommandAwareState<T>> LedgerTransaction.matchLinearStatesByCommand(ofType: Class<K>): Map<T,List<InOutState<K>>>{



    groupStates<K,UniqueIdentifier> { it.linearId }.let {

        var mapByCommand = mutableMapOf<T,MutableList<InOutState<K>>>()
        it.forEach {

            if(mapByCommand.containsKey(it.outputs.single().command)){

                mapByCommand.get(it.outputs.single().command)?.add(InOutState(it.inputs.noneOrSingle(),it.outputs.noneOrSingle()))

            }else{

                mapByCommand.put(it.outputs.single().command, mutableListOf(InOutState(it.inputs.noneOrSingle(),it.outputs.noneOrSingle())))

            }


        }
        return mapByCommand
    }

}
```